# Como interagir vários menu dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho dois menus, qual função fazer e como fazer, para quando abrir um, fechar o outro? E ao clicar fora do menu fechar também? Obrigado!

**Meu código**

```js
function menu1() {
    document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle('visivel')
    
  }

  function menu2() {
    document.getElementById('dropdown2').classList.toggle('visivel')
    
  }
```

```css
.submenu {
    display: none;
}

.visivel {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <button onclick="menu1()">BOTAO</button>
          <div class="submenu" id="dropdown">
              <div>conteudo1</div>
              <div>conteudo2</div>
              <div>conteudo3</div>
              <div>conteudo4</div>
              <div>conteudo5</div>
          </div>

          <button onclick="menu2()">BOTAO2</button>
          <div class="submenu" id="dropdown2">
              <div>conteudo1</div>
              <div>conteudo2</div>
              <div>conteudo3</div>
              <div>conteudo4</div>
              <div>conteudo5</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tentou? `function menu1() {
    document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle('visivel'); document.getElementById('dropdown2').classList.toggle("submenu");  
    
  }

  function menu2() {
    document.getElementById('dropdown2').classList.toggle('visivel'); document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("submenu");
    
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma forma mais genérica de se fazer isso sem ter que criar uma função para cada botão e usar id's. Basta colocar uma classe nos botões a adicionar *events handlers* a todos. Ao clicar no botão irá buscar o elemento adjacente (que vem após) com `.nextElementSibling`.

Criar também um *event handler* para o `document` que irá ocultar todos os menus quando você clicar fora dele ou dos botões.

Veja abaixo como fica com comentários explicativos do que o código faz:

```js
// pega todos os botões pela classe
const botoes = document.querySelectorAll(".botaomenu");

// cria um evento para o document
document.onclick = function(){
   // percorre todos os menus e remove a classe
   for(let menu of botoes){
      menu.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("visivel");
   }
}

// percorre todos os botões e cria os eventos
for(let menu of botoes){
   menu.onclick = function(e){
      e.stopPropagation(); // impede que o clique atinja o document
      let visivel = document.querySelector(".visivel"); // busca um menu visível
      // se houver um menu visivel, oculta ele desde que não seja o referente ao botão clicado
      if(visivel && visivel != e.target.nextElementSibling) visivel.classList.remove("visivel");
      // altera a classe
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('visivel');
   }
   // impede que o document seja atinjido ao clica dentro do menu
   menu.nextElementSibling.onclick = function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
}
```

```css
.submenu {
    display: none;
}

.visivel {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button class="botaomenu">BOTAO</button>
<div class="submenu">
   <div>conteudo1</div>
   <div>conteudo2</div>
   <div>conteudo3</div>
   <div>conteudo4</div>
   <div>conteudo5</div>
</div>

<button class="botaomenu">BOTAO2</button>
<div class="submenu">
   <div>conteudo122</div>
   <div>conteudo2</div>
   <div>conteudo32</div>
   <div>conteudo42</div>
   <div>conteudo52</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado professor pela sua explicação! Funcionou perfeito.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia fazer uma query para selecionar todos os outros submenus e então remover a class `visivel`

```
// busca todos os elementos com a classe submenu, exceto o com ID dropdown2
for (var outroSubmenu of document.querySelectorAll('.submenu:not(#dropdown2)')) {
    outroSubmenu.classList.remove('visivel')
}

document.getElementById('dropdown2').classList.toggle('visivel')
```

Outra melhoria seria criar uma única função para manipular todos os submenus, e receber como parâmetro o id do elemento clicado:

```js
function toggleMenu(id) {
    for (var outroSubmenu of document.querySelectorAll(`.submenu:not(#${id})`)) {
        outroSubmenu.classList.remove('visivel')
    }
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('visivel')
}
```

```css
.submenu {
    display: none;
}

.visivel {
    display: block;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <button onclick="toggleMenu('dropdown')">BOTAO</button>
          <div class="submenu" id="dropdown">
              <div>conteudo1</div>
              <div>conteudo2</div>
              <div>conteudo3</div>
              <div>conteudo4</div>
              <div>conteudo5</div>
          </div>

          <button onclick="toggleMenu('dropdown2')">BOTAO2</button>
          <div class="submenu" id="dropdown2">
              <div>conteudo6</div>
              <div>conteudo7</div>
              <div>conteudo8</div>
              <div>conteudo9</div>
              <div>conteudo10</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, e se fosse com 4 menus? a ideia eh a mesma?

Comment: Sim, como `querySelectorAll` busca todos os submenus, não importa que você tenha 2 ou 100 deles, contanto que eles tenham a classe `submenu`, todos eles serão "fechados".

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela sua explicação!